# Cannot install ubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dependencies, desktop-environments

I am sorry for this newbie question. I removed my desktop manager and many gnome packages by mistake in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I tried `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, which leads to:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (= 42.0-1ubuntu6) but 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3 is to be installed
        Depends: libgdm1 (= 42.0-1ubuntu6) but 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3 is to be installed
 nautilus : Depends: gvfs (>= 1.3.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (= 1:42.0-1ubuntu2) but 1:42.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: nautilus-data (= 1:42.0-1ubuntu2) but 1:42.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Recommends: gvfs-backends
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.99.22) but 0.99.22.7 is to be installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.17 is to be installed
                               Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.17 is to be installed
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:22.04.9) but 1:22.04.10 is to be installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.192.54) but 3.192.54.6 is to be installed
```

so I tried to install the dependencies one by one with the specific versions. I tried:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt install gir1.2-gdm-1.0=42.0-1ubuntu6
sudo apt install libgdm1=42.0-1ubuntu6
sudo apt install gvfs=1.3.2
sudo apt install libnautilus-extension1a=1:42.0-1ubuntu2
sudo apt install nautilus-data=1:42.0-1ubuntu2
```

and I get errors for each one. for example:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Version '42.0-1ubuntu6
   ' for 'libgdm1' was not found

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

or

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package 

Version '1.3.2
   ' for 'gvfs' was not found
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  gvfs:i386
```

Here is the output of `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/ jammy main restricted
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
#deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
```

and also the output of `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:# deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-jammy.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:# deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```

how can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you simply forgot to `update` before the original attempt to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package. After running the `update`, gdm3 should depend on the **newer** gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (i.e. 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3) so you shouldn't be trying to force the older package. What happens if you run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` now?

Comment: @steeldriver - hi. yes, I did and nothing changes.

Comment: ... meaning you get the same error, or meaning it doesn't fix the original problem?

Comment: @steeldriver - after I ran the update successfully, when I run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` I get the same error and the original problem persists.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: @nobody - I added my repo sources in the question.

Comment: Please remove under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` every file with suffix `.save` and remove in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list` the armf and arm64 stuff. Then `sudo apt update` then try again.

Comment: @nobody - I did what you said, but the result did not change. I still got the same error. however, I found the solution and fixed it. you can see my answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my problem. This is what I did:

opened my sources:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then added these two lines to it:

```
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

then updated my apt:

```
sudo apt update
```

and eventually I could install the desktop manager:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

I don't know exactly what those lines containing `jammy-updates` and `jammy-backports` mean but it solved my issue. I had other options like `jammy` and `jammy-security` but missed two above entries.

it would be still useful if somebody explains what those entries are and how they solved the problem. Now I got my desktop again. thank you all.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! For some mysterious reason, an apt install command completely obliterated my system, uninstalling a ton of packages. It even tried to uninstall "sudo", that's where it failed and stopped! WTF. Anyhow, this tip was the first step to getting it fixed. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy it helped you @superiggy